# How to fix the results of loop

Tags: c#

I'm inputing the number like 1 or high number and want the result like this :  `"1,2 hop!", "1,2,3 hop!"`

This is for C# in Visual Studio, I have tried to put the array in the variable but cannot got the expected results.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int angka;
        Console.WriteLine("Masukkan Angka : ");
        angka = Console.Read();
        for( int i = 0; i<angka;i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(angka.ToString()+ " + Hop !");
            int y = 0;
            if ((int)y == angka)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the output of 2 is `1,2 hop!`, but the actual output is like this :

```
Masukkan Angka :
3

51 Hop !
51 Hop !
51 Hop !
51 Hop !
51 Hop !
51 Hop !
51 Hop !
51 Hop !
51 Hop !
51 Hop !
51 Hop !
51 Hop !
51 Hop !
51 Hop !
51 Hop !
51 Hop !
51 Hop !
51 Hop !
51 Hop !
51 Hop !
51 Hop !
51 Hop !
51 Hop !
51 Hop !
51 Hop !
51 Hop !
51 Hop !
51 Hop !
51 Hop !
51 Hop !
51 Hop !
```

Comment: if you call Console.Read() and press 3 and Enter, the result is the char code of the literal '3' which is 51

Comment: For such a small amount of code, there are many things wrong, i think you should keep working at this. start with @DarkSquirrel42 comment, and use `Console.ReadLine()`. then work out how to convert it to int

Comment: www.asciitable.com

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution for your question can be....

```
            int angka;
            Console.WriteLine("Masukkan Angka : ");
            angka =Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            string result =$"{string.Join(",",Enumerable.Range(1,angka).ToList())} hop!";
```

You have used Console.Read() which gives you ascii value of enter(as DarkSquirrel42 commented). other then this you are not so much clear about desired output and applied logic.

like...

```
Console.WriteLine(angka.ToString()+ " + Hop !");  //you always print angka which is not changed and remain same for all output..thus it's print always 51(enter's ascii)
```

And

```
 int y = 0; //Generally we don't declare variables within a single loop beacuse on each iteration it will be reinitialize.
```

And

```
if ((int)y == angka)  //this will break it in first iteration...explicit conversion is not requied
{
  break;
}
```

Comment: "Generally we don't declare variables within a single loop because on each iteration it will be reinitialize." is very strange recommendation at best... Why would you extend scope of variable outside of scope where it is used?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
int angka;
Console.WriteLine("Masukkan Angka :");
angka = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
for (int i = 1; i <= angka; i++)
{
    Console.Write(i.ToString() + (i == angka ? " hop!" :  ","));
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Masukkan Angka : ");
        int angka = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 1; i <= angka; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(i + ", ");
        }

        Console.Write(" hop! ");

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of issues here...

1. Inside a loop, you declare `int y` and then additinally cast to an `int`: `(int)y`, which is totally unnecessary. Moreover, you assign 0 to `y` and check againt `angka`, which will always be false, unless you assign 0 to `angka`, but in that case, loop wouldn't be executed (due to condition `i < angka`). So this piece of code could be deleted entirely.
2. Your desired result suggest you want to write consecutive numbers separated by a comma, so you need to use `Console.Write(i + ",")` inside your loop, because `angka` is constant inside a loop and writing this variable to console will print the same number every time. After a loop, you should call `Console.Write(" hop!");`

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int angka = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Masukkan Angka : ");
        while (angka < 1 || angka > 9)
        {
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out angka);
            if (angka < 1 || angka > 9)
            { Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number between 1 and 9"); }
        }
        System.Text.StringBuilder resultString = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 1; i <= angka; i++)
        {
            resultString.Append(i.ToString());
            resultString.Append(i < angka ? "," : " hop!");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(resultString.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int angka;
        Console.WriteLine("Masukkan Angka : ");
        angka = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 1; i < angka; i++)
        {
            if(i==1)
            {
                Console.Write(i);
            }
            else
                Console.Write(","+i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(" hop!");
        Console.ReadKey();
```